# Tooltip in angularjs ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display a tootltip on the top of each element on the first TD. But since its in the ng-repeat, many tooltips(badly designed) are showing up. How can I show it just on the top of the td I am hovering? I cannot use angular UI on this. Please help me out. Thanks!

http://plnkr.co/edit/UJ8UDaTHaACZwX7uw5B8?p=info

```
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <td ng-mouseover="positive()" ng-mouseleave="negative()">{{friend.name}}
      <hover ng-show="showHover"></hover>
        </td>
        <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.gender}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the title attribute that is available to all html elements. This is good from accessibility perspective.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends">
            <td ng-mouseover="positive()" ng-mouseleave="negative()" title="{{tooltipText}} - {{friend.name}}">
                {{friend.name}}
            </td>
            <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.gender}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

If you need to style the tooltip check if this link helps.

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to have a unique name for each tooltip, in this case you can use the name or $index:

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    <td ng-mouseover="positive(friend.name)" ng-mouseleave="negative(friend.name)">
        {{friend.name}}
        <hover ng-show="showHover[friend.name]"></hover>
    </td>
    <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.gender}}</td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$scope.showHover = {};

$scope.positive = function(name) {

    $scope.showHover[name] = true;

    if (name.indexOf('*') > -1) {
        $scope.tooltipText = "Changed value";
    }
    if (name.indexOf('-') > -1) {
        $scope.tooltipText = "No Data"          
    } else {
        $scope.tooltipText = "Original value";
    }
}

$scope.negative = function(name) {
    $scope.showHover[name] = false;
}
```